# Создание полос прокрутки для настройки времени

Tags: c#, wpf, .net

Добрый день!

Подскажите как создать полосу прокрутки на подобии таких:
[image: Настройка часов]

В сети конкретных решений не нашел, буду рад конкретным или приближенным идеям, или ссылкам на инструкции.

Comment: Это скриншот с телефона? Там должен быть нативный контрол.

Comment: Например: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/279704/iOS-UIPickerView-like-control-in-WPF

Comment: @Vlad , скриншот взят с pinterest для того, что бы показать то, что нужно получить) Мне нужно реализовать такое в декстопном приложении, с возможностью прокрутки мышью)

Comment: @UporotayaPanda: А, ну тогда руками придётся писать, конечно. Только это не самое хорошее задание: пользоваться нужно на каждой системе нативными контролами, они подходят лучше. Например, выбор часа из списка на телефоне удобен, а на компе не очень.

Comment: @Vlad: а что тогда предложите? Так как мой опыт не столь велик, как у вас...

Comment: @UporotayaPanda: Проще всего, вероятно, найти библиотеку, в которой это уже реализовано :) Я бы реализовывал вручную, на основе горизонтального ListView или там ItemsControl'а + scrolling. Но менять поведение придётся сильно -> много code-behind.

Comment: @Vlad: Но написание подобного контрола дало бы хороший опыт в wpf.

Comment: @UporotayaPanda: Ну это да.